# Running Facebook Login / Publish as Seperate Class

Tags: android, facebook

I have followed : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/ 
I have created a separate page as in the example and works perfectly fine.

My issue is now I want to add the Login button to my home page and the publish button on a different page. Is it possible to convert this into a separate class that I can call from anywhere?

Has anyone done this and can point my in the right direction.
Sorry if this has been asked before. I am very new to Facebook SDK

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use the Active Session, you should be able to call Session.getActiveSession() from any activity, and it should return you the right thing. So the page with the login button would create the active session, and the page with the publish button would get the active session, and call requestNewPublishPermission and do the publish.

There are 2 outstanding issues:

1. You need to ensure that the page with the login button appears in your app before the page with the publish button (at least the first time, when the user initially logs in).
2. In subsequent restarts of your app (after the user has already logged in), you can use the UiLifecycleHelper to manage, restore, and auto-open the active session for you.

Comment: Got the Publish working but I put the Login button in a different activity which is not being called. How would I convert the login to be in a separate class so can call it from a couple of buttons through out the app